# JPQL - combine multiple fields in the IN expression

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I am wondering if there is a way to write a JPQL statement similar to the one below

```
select o from entity1 o where (o.field1, o.field2) IN (select value1, value2 from ...)
```

The similar sql query works in Oracle 10g. However, in eclipselink, I got this error:

```
syntax error at [,].
Internal Exception: MismatchedTokenException(81!=84)
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException.syntaxErrorAt(JPQLException.java:362)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.handleRecognitionException(JPQLParser.java:301)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.addError(JPQLParser.java:242)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.reportError(JPQLParser.java:359)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
KL

Answer (score 0):

This kind of query is not covered by the JPA specification (neither 1 nor 2). However, Hibernate does support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a native SQL query for this, or perhaps use a join instead of a subselect.

EclipseLink does support this in Expression queries, but not currently in JPQL.
(not all databases support this though)